# Restrict brush width in a dc.js (ordinal) chart?

Tags: dc.js

I'd like to restrict the width of a brush in a dc.js chart, e.g., so the user can't shrink it to less than X.  I'd also like it to work with rounding, so if I have a time scale rounded to months, then I'd like to say don't let the user shrink the brush to less than 2 months, but still snap to discrete month boundaries.  And, I also want to do something similar for an ordinal scale, with a brush that only lets you select a single value and snaps to those values.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The dc.js brush has extent() which gives back the two ends of the brush.  One can detect one end and then use a conditional to limit the "range" of the brush...

Something like:

```
// grab the two ends of the brush
var extent = brush.extent();
    if ((extent[1] - extent[0]) > myBiggestBrush) {
    console.log("Extent too large");
extent[1] = extent[0] + myBiggestBrush;
}
//then use the extent in the brush
d3.select("g.brush")
   .call(brush.extent(extent));
```

For keeping the brush to single units - check out:
https://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/d8dff2fa37345d54f9e58eb74db460d0

Comment: Also, there is [chart.round](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#coordinategridmixinroundround--function--coordinategridmixin) and the undocumented but safe-to-override [chart.extendBrush](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/coordinate-grid-mixin.js#L1018-L1028), which both modify the brush after it changes.

Comment: what is myBiggestBrush? and is brush a dc.js object? also why did you link a d3.js implementation to a dc.js problem